# Remove button after picking image

Tags: iphone, uibutton, uiimagepickercontroller

I have `UIImagePickerController` for pick image from photoLibrary. After picking image from photoLibrary, i need to remove or hide button from view. But button is still showing after picking image.

Code;

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
photopick= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [photopick setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    // [overlayButton setFrame:CGRectMake(80, 420, 60, 30)];

    [photopick setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 80, 50)];

    [photopick addTarget:self action:@selector(showAlbum:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [[self view] addSubview:photopick];
}

-(void)showAlbum:(id)sender{

    imagePicker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];

    imagePicker.delegate = self;

    imagePicker.allowsEditing =NO;

    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

   // imagePicker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;


    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];



}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker{
    //release picker
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

    -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
    {
       //set image

       [photopick removeFromSuperview];


       newImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]];

       [newImage setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)];
       [self.view addSubview:newImage];

       [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
    }
```

Comment: To hide: [back_btn setHidden:YES]

Comment: Your way of removing the button seems right...

Comment: But it's not removing..

Comment: It's not working. Your is correct. But why it's not hiding after image picker

Comment: What is this button? IBOutlet? Did you create it programmatically? Are you on a background thread?

Comment: When i launch app,button displays for photo pick. when i click this button, UIImagePicker activate and image will pick. After picking image, i need to hide this button

Comment: Sorry I'm confused. What is this button, did you create it?

Comment: show your button creation code

Comment: Did You Linked the IBOutlet of button in Interface Builder. Any code on IBOutlet button will not work until you link the button **back_btn** with proper IBOutlet in the Interface Builder.

Comment: What is the value of back_btn? If it's nil, make sure that you have linked the back button in IB to the variable.

Comment: what's the button called now? Your code is too hard to trace.

Comment: That's simple button. When click this button it invokes imagePicker.

Answer (score 0):

Well,I found one problem in here

> after dismissing model view controller viewDidAppear method calling
>   every time

it means every time new object(photopick)created and added to the view that's why photopick appearing after removing from the view.you can keep photopick button code in `viewDidLoad`.